# Как использовать хуки в сервисах React

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Как я могу использовать хуки (например useNavigate) внутри сервисов? Например у меня есть сервис ApiService с функцией resetLogin, который перенаправляет на главную страницу, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Без примера кода, понять, что вы хотите сделать, проблематично

Comment: Кто просветит что такое "сервисы React"?

Comment: Про хуки React одно можно сказать точно - применять их можно только внутри функциональных компонентов и пользовательских хуков. Если пресловутый "сервис React" ни то, ни другое - хуки там не доступны.